# Ubuntu 16.04 WiFi dropping on WPA group rekeying

Tags: wireless, network-manager, disconnect, wpa

This issue has been bothered me for a while now.
Whenever my WiFi drops, it shows this in the syslog:

```
Jun 13 19:56:38 hp-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[1008]: wlo1: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 00:23:69:2e:53:57 [GTK=CCMP]
```

And my WiFi does not automatically reconnect.
I need to manually restart network-manager to restore the connection.

Is there a way to prevent this issue?
Looking forward to your reply, thanks!

Output: **lspci -knn | grep Net -A2**

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter + BT 4.0 combo adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Group key should not be the issue. You can disable reniewing group key in the router. It is only for multicast.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 2):

What fixed it for me was going to Edit Connections, choosing the particular connection, going to the IPV6 tab, and setting it to "Ignore".

That looks like IPV6 group rekeying.

Ubuntu has issues with their IPV6 on some systems.   Mine worked great for 5 years.  Then a after a routine update, it would drop consistently every 20 minutes.    Disabled the IPV6, and back in business.

Answer (score 0):

Try `wpa_cli log_level warning` as root to change default INFO level to WARNING.

Looks like extra config file and wpa_supplicant startup tuning required to make this permanent.